# React-Native FlatList- Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop, even after giving key={index}

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building the photo-feed application, [project-repo-here](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/exchange-o-gram/commits/master) , in the comments section after clicking on show-comments, it shows comment page on a device, but in a terminal, it breaks with error as,

error is in comments.js file.

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See documentationOfREact/react-warning-keys for more information.%s, 

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`., , 
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:687)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:662)
    in FlatList (at comments.js:212)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in comments (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:795)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:69)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:59)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:57)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:27)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:860)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:311)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.js:307)
    in Handler (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:70)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:217:39 in warningWithoutStack
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:617:32 in warning
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1429:14 in validateExplicitKey
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1451:28 in validateChildKeys
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1619:22 in cloneElementWithValidation
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:947:6 in render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10563:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14091:21 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14129:41 in workLoop
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14226:15 in renderRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15193:17 in performWorkOnRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15090:24 in performWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15047:14 in performSyncWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14925:19 in requestWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14711:16 in scheduleWork
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7700:17 in enqueueSetState
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:364:31 in setState
* app/screens/comments.js:66:22 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I am displaying comments-array using flatList and gave

`keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              item.id;
            }}`

also, I tried giving key={index}, but same error.
I gave unique key as index to , but error occurs,

flatList component is

```
   <FlatList
        refreshing={this.state.refresh}
        data={this.state.comments_list}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          item.id;
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#eee" }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View
            key={item.id}
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              overflow: "hidden",
              marginBottom: 5,
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              borderColor: "grey"
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
              <Text>time: {item.timestamp}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.author}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View>
              <Text>{item.comment}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
```

firebase structure is this
[image: structureOfDB]

Comment: "keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          item.id;
        }}"


   your not returning the key. plz return it


 "keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          return item.id;
        }}"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to return the Key like this

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
```

Comment: thanks Rishabh, it worked, that keyword `return`, else is the same. I am following a tutorial, but the tutor does not return item.id, he simply gives the item.id like I did, but how didn't he get any error, without returning key?

Comment: then he must be using this () brackets instead of {} like this 
keyExtractor={(item, index) => (
          return item.id;
        )}

Comment: nope, here is screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/ZrAdWWy , also, it's same even after using `index as key` instead of `item.id`

Comment: if you see closely he is not using any kind of brackets he is simply returning it by `keyExtractor={(value, index) => index.toString()}` if you don't use any braces it will simply return the result

Comment: checked & Upvoted your answer. okay Rishabh, I got it. "If we use `{}` then we have to manually return key, if not then it automatically returns, am I right?. I wish to know this before two days while I was finding the error in all modules.

Comment: Yes exactly this is how it goes

Comment: I use to follow `{}` for indentation and see code without ambiguity, but it makes one keyword extra as "return", compared to inline return func doesn't need "return". thanks @Rishabh.

Comment: This concept of not needing the `return` statement, by excluding the `{}` is based on the concept of explicit returns from arrow functions I believe.

Answer (score 8):

```
return ( <FlatList
        data={options}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
         return  index.toString();
        }}
        renderItem={_renderItem2}
/>);
```

remember to use return when using the {} bracket, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't need any search functions in my list, so keyExtractor is unimportant to me at the moment; however, you can directly solve this problem by adding the line below.

```
<FlatList
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} //Add this line
  style={{...}}
  data={...}
  renderItem={info => {...}}/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                            return index.toString();
                        }}
  renderItem={(item, index) => (

                            <View key={index}>
                                <View style={{ margin: 6 }}>


                                    <Item/>

                                </View>
                            </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

keyExtractor show warning message even due to spacing. Best way is always return the key. For example

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                return(item.id);
             }}
```

or else you can eliminate spacing

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) =>item.id}
```